# Split a string into String Array in c#

Tags: c#, split

How do I split the string into a string array.

My string looks like this

```
string orgString = "1234-|@$@|-George,Michael -$@%@$-65489-|@$@|-Lawrence,  Steve J  -$@%@$-7897954-|@$@|-Oliver Mike  -$@%@$-56465-|@$@|-Waldimir Tursoky";
```

Now I want my string array to store name and number along with `-|@$@|-`

I tried the following code

```
string[] strArray = orgString.Split(new string[] {"-$@%@$-"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

My output looks like this:

```
"1234-|@$@|-George,Michael "
```

But my desired output is (name first, number last)

```
"George,Michael -|@$@|-1234"
```

How can i achieve this in C#?

Comment: Step #1 is to use/show *compiling* C# code..

Comment: You can use split on hyphen '-' instead, then you have the chance to rearrange the strings.

Comment: Sounds like regex is more suitable to extract these values

Comment: @RufusL updated my code.It will compile now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just swap parts in the resulting string :

```
string orgString = "1234-|@$@|-George,Michael -$@%@$-65489-|@$@|-Lawrence,  Steve J  -$@%@$-7897954-|@$@|-Oliver Mike  -$@%@$-56465-|@$@|-Waldimir Tursoky";
string[] resultingList = orgString.Split(new string[] {"-$@%@$-"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x=>x.Split(new string[] {"-|@$@|-"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Aggregate((x11,y)=>{return y+" -|@$@|- "+x11;})).ToArray();
foreach(string result in resultingList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it. Cant we have it in the string array instead of var.?

Comment: @Santosh yes, but you will need to add cast in that case.

Comment: @Santosh I have changed my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can split again and then recombine

```
string outerDivider = "-$@%@$-";
string innerDivider = "-|@$@|-";

var results = orgString
    // Split by outer divider
    .Split(new string[] { outerDivider }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    // Then for each of the results, split again on the inner divider
    .Select(x => x.Split(new string[] { innerDivider }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    // Swap the order of elements around the inner divider and recombine into a string
    .Select(x => string.Join(innerDivider, x[1], x[0]));
```